# Find homography if rotation is known

Tags: augmented-reality, homography

For an Augmented Reality app, we use a library to compute an homography from 2 sets of points via Ransac and DTL.
Cool.
But we know the rotation (mobile sensors) so we think it could all be made quicker and more accurately.
What would be your advice ?
Thanks for your insights,

Michaël